# Is Unity turning into our jQuery?

Tags: discussion

I hope not.... [just sayin'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the issue, but is this appropriate for **meta**? For discussions *about* the site operation?

Comment: I think memes are inherently meta, so I guess it's OK!

Comment: what's wrong with Jquery?

Comment: @Spooks, on StackOverflow javascript questions are likely to get an answer suggesting jQeruy, whether that is helpful or not. So jquery has made it into a mem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492

Answer (score 3):

Would have never even made that association. But yep, It appears so, but honestly... it's so hard. It's really just that easy and that usable.

Comment: Same with jQuery. You should totally drop Untiy and try jQuery.